# Struts2 Action mapping error

Tags: struts2, mapping, action

I am new to Struts2, I have been facing an action mapping issue in my Application. The error message says

> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> Messages: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name "yourActionName".
>   Stacktraces
>
> There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name "yourActionName". - [unknown location]
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:178)
>       org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
>      ...

The issue is intermittent and it occurs like very rarely. I have verified the action mapping in struts config file and also in JSP action seems to be correctly mapped. As far as I have understood, sometimes the action tries to map to wrong namespace. 
I have defined the namespaces in all the concerned JSP. Nothing seems to be wrong with the controller layer.

Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The same problem came into my application you should change your filter name

```
 <filter-class>
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
 </filter-class>
```

and after that you should clean your project then run it again if you get error then change 
the filter by this

```
 <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
```

Do same process that is mentioned above it will work correctly because dispatcher.FilterDispatcher is deprecated after struts2.3.